# Change Jquery AJAX post URL based on radio button

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I currently have a product search box; you can search via Cartridge Name or Printer Name. Those are different SQL queries, so I have made the appropriate PHP files for the queries, but I am having trouble getting Jquery to check the value of the radio button and then modify the post file based on that radio button.

It needs to check for the radio button update anytime a user does anything with the form of course.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Here is the Jquery:

```
            $("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");
        $("#faq_search_input").keyup(function()
        {
            var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;
            if(faq_search_input.length>1)
            {
                var search_method = $("#search_method").val();
                if(search_method == 'Cartridge'){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>/resources/ajax-search.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        beforeSend:  function() {
                            $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
                        },
                        success: function(server_response){
                            $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
                            $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);

                            if ($('input#faq_search_input').hasClass("loading")) {
                                $("input#faq_search_input").removeClass("loading");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>/resources/ajax-search2.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        beforeSend:  function() {
                            $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
                        },
                        success: function(server_response){
                            $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
                            $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);

                            if ($('input#faq_search_input').hasClass("loading")) {
                                $("input#faq_search_input").removeClass("loading");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }return false;
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>controllers/product_Search_Process.Controllers.php" method="get">
<div style="width:885px;padding-left:15px;height:127px;padding-top:50px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-image:url(<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>/display/img/layout/ink_and_toner_finder.png);">
    <div style="width:400px;height:108px;float:left;padding-top:7px;">
        <div style="width:400px;padding-left:20px;float:left;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Printer Brand</option>
                    <?php getTierOne(); ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="width:80px;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;float:left;">
                <span id="wait_1">
                    <img alt="Please Wait" src="<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>display/img/ui/ajax-loader.gif"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
        <span id="result_2" style="display: none;"></span>

    </div>
    <div style="width:70px;height:115px;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width:400px;float:left;">
        <h2 style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;padding-left:10px;">Search by Cartridge or Printer</h2>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;">
            <span style="padding-left:10px;"><input type="radio" name="search_method" value="Cartridge" checked>Cartridge</span>
            <span style="padding-left:20px;"><input type="radio" name="search_method" value="Printer">Printer</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div style="padding-top:5px;">
                <div style="padding-top:5px;float:left;">
                    <input type="text" name="search_text" style="float:left;width:230px;" id="faq_search_input"/>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-left:18px;float:left;">
                    <input id="submit_right" type="submit" name="submit_right" value="Find Ink!" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="searchresultdata" class="faq-articles"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whether the only change is the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the selected radio box you can use `$('input:radio[name="search_method"]:checked').val();`

```
$("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");
$("#faq_search_input").keyup(function() {
    updateResult();
    return false;
});

$('input[name="search_method"]').on('click', updateResult)

function updateResult(){
    var faq_search_input = $('#faq_search_input').val();
    var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;
    if(faq_search_input.length>1)
    {
        var search_method = $('input:radio[name="search_method"]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $site_Config_Url; ?>/resources/ajax-search" + (search_method == 'Cartridge'? '': '2') + ".php",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend:  function() {
                $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
            },
            success: function(server_response){
                $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
                $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);

                if ($('input#faq_search_input').hasClass("loading")) {
                    $("input#faq_search_input").removeClass("loading");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can you recommend the best way to add a listener to the radio buttons so, if the user has already typed something in and changes the radio button, the query will re-run as well?

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working. I type in '23' and then change the radio button but the results don't change. I tried modifying your example to: `$('input[name="search_method"]').change(function() {
 updateResult();
});` but that didn't work either

Comment: can you type `$('input[name="search_method"]')` in your console and see whether the radio buttons are returned?

Comment: Also whether the previous functionality is working? Also check your console for any errors

Comment: The code you've provided works completely other than the radio button change update; its using the appropriate PHP files and everything the way it needs to =)

Comment: Can you add a `console.log('searching')` at the beginning of `updateResult` to see whether the method is getting called when you click on radio

Comment: which jquery version is used? I was checking it with a fiddle and ajax calls seems to be sending at Ihttp://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eyc2Q/

Comment: Like this? `function updateResult(){
 console.log('searching');
    var faq_search_input = $('#faq_search_input').val();` if so, no nothing is showing up in the log when I change radio buttons. The functionality is all good other than the radio button update; its still switching the AJAX PHP processors appropriately.

Comment: what is the jquery version used

Comment: try changing `$('input[name="search_method"]').on('click', updateResult)` to `$('input[name="search_method"]').click(updateResult)`

Comment: Im getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25372/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-ihateartists)